# Redirect tail -f output of each line to curl variable

Tags: bash, curl

Trying to parse each line of a log file I am tailing to curl as a variable.

Currently I have this:

```
tail -f log.txt |
buffer |
while read -r LINE; do
  curl -s -X POST https://api.com -d id=-123456 -d text="'$LINE'"
done
```

It's not really working and my goal is to output each line as a variable inside the text field: text=$LINE

How can I accomplish this? Is it an issue with the variable?

Comment: Please, read how to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also your one-liner is missing a `done` at the end.

Comment: what are you trying to mean by calling buffer in the pipeline `.. | buffer | ..`